# Image Watch shows invalid image

Tags: c++, image-processing, visual-studio-2015

I tried the first example at the extensibilty section from here:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/ivm/imagewatchhelp/imagewatchhelp.htm#_Toc351981452

Here is my code:

```
#include <memory>
struct My8BitRGBImage
{
    unsigned int ncols;
    unsigned int nrows;
    unsigned char* data;
};

void main()
{
    unsigned int ncols = 100;
    unsigned int nrows = 100;
    unsigned int bufferSize = ncols * nrows * 3;
    unsigned char * data = new unsigned char[bufferSize];
    memset(data, 0, bufferSize);
    My8BitRGBImage image = { ncols, nrows, data };
}
```

When I break at the last line and try to watch the image I am getting invalid:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ6BV.png)

At the ImageWatch.log it seems like My8BitRGBImage is registered correctly:

```
+ Parsing ImageWatchFrameBuffer.natvis ...
+ Found type My8BitRGBImage ...
+ -> Registering My8BitRGBImage
```

ImageWatchFrameBuffer.nativs Looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">

  <UIVisualizer ServiceId="{A452AFEA-3DF6-46BB-9177-C0B08F318025}" Id="1"
                MenuName="Add to Image Watch"/>

  <Type Name="My8BitRGBImage">
    <UIVisualizer ServiceId="{A452AFEA-3DF6-46BB-9177-C0B08F318025}" Id="1" />
  </Type>

  <Type Name="My8BitRGBImage">
    <Expand>
      <Synthetic Name="[type]">
        <DisplayString>UINT8</DisplayString>
      </Synthetic>
      <Synthetic Name="[channels]">
        <DisplayString>RGB</DisplayString>
      </Synthetic>
      <Item Name="[width]">ncols</Item>
      <Item Name="[height]">nrows</Item>
      <Item Name="[data]">data</Item>
      <Item Name="[stride]">ncols*3</Item>
    </Expand>
  </Type>  

</AutoVisualizer>
```

Copy paste from the example.
I am using VS2015 update 1.
What could be the problem?

Comment: I have now the situation that an image on the stack as local variable is not displayed while the same type as shared_ptr is displayed in this extension.

Comment: @dorperetz, did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<Item Name="[channels]">3</Item>
```

instead of

```
<Synthetic Name="[channels]">
    <DisplayString>RGB</DisplayString>
</Synthetic>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just disable Native Edit and Continue mode and you can solve this problem

[image]